# HttpPostedFileBase to byte array make exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc 4

i have this model : `ViewModelOne`

```
public HttpPostedFileBase passportImage { get; set; }
```

Also, I have this model: `modelViewTWO`

```
public byte[] passportImage { get; set; }
```

I have this View witch use ViewModelOne as a model

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.passportImage, new { placeholder = "Uploadt Your Passport", type = "file"})
```

I have this controller:

```
public string Register(ViewModelOne newT) {
modelViewTWO second = new modelViewTWO();
byte[] data;
            using (Stream inputStream = newT.passportImage.InputStream)
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                if (memoryStream == null)
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }
                data = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            second.passportImage = data;
}
```

I got this exception

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

in this line

```
newT.passportImage.InputStream
```

#### Edit

I check that newT.passportImage and It is null. why?

Comment: On what line did you get the exception? On the one starting with ``using``?

Comment: @acfrancis yes that line

Comment: @acfrancis check the edit pleaes

Comment: Sounds like `passportImage` is null. You should make sure it isn't before the `using`. Also make sure the form tag has the `enctype` attribute.

Comment: @JLe yet is is null, i make an edit to the questoin, so please what am i doing wrong in the `view` so it is not passing the passportImage ?

Comment: @JLe it is encrypted like this `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Is the ``Register()`` method called by the controller action? Can you show us that code to be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `enctype` attribute to the form tag so the data gets posted as well:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
```

(setting the first two parameters to `null` will post the same action and controller the form is on.